# I'm looking for a sci fi novel from the 70's; 10th planet, kidnapped F geneticist

Tags: story-identification, novel

The book was about 2 species of aliens were working together, the Ell or El who lived on a warm wet planet with many types of moss and fungus and the females laid eggs, and the Vorn or Varn who used to have patagia and were having fertility problems, so they kidnapped a female geneticist, or virologist to help them. I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Was the word “patagia” specifically used in the story? It’s quite an unusual word in literary contexts, so that might help with identification.

Comment: Is that [patagia as in membranous wings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patagium)?

Comment: Just to clarify -- does the reference in your title to "10th planet" mean you're sure these aliens were supposed to inhabit a previously-unknown planet that was located right here in our own Solar System?

Comment: Yes, they had vestigial marks down the arms and torso on both sides